# Querying based on user profile

Tags: query, metadata, tooling-api, user-profile

I want to write queries to check what

1. apps
2. page layouts
3. lightning components
4. fields

are accessible to a particular user profile for a particular object. I also want to find out whether the user profile includes permission to edit a field.

I was looking into the Tooling API to see if I can achieve this, haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Must it be a query? Could it be, for example, a Describe call?

Comment: anything that provides me that information should be fine, but my mentor did point out toolingAPI in particular so I was wondering if that's the answer

Comment: Do you need the permissions for the *current* user, or any *arbitrary* user? That would change the potential answer, to be sure.

Comment: @sfdcfox , the scenario should be that given any user profile, I should be able to query what apps, page layouts, components and fields can it access and what kind of access. As a consequence, given a user profile and field/layout/component/app, I should be able to query to see if the profile can view/edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Field Permissions:**

```
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
    FROM FieldPermissions 
    WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' 
    AND parentId IN ( SELECT id 
                        FROM permissionset 
                        WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = '<Profile Name>')
```

**Page layouts:**

Manually: Setup > Object Manager > Object > Page Layouts. Then select the button 'Page Layout Assignment'. This will show you a list of your profiles and which page layouts are assigned to which one for this object by record type.

Using Tooling API:

```
SELECT Layout.Name, Layout.TableEnumOrId, ProfileId, Profile.Name, RecordTypeId FROM ProfileLayout WHERE Layout.TableEnumOrId = '<Object name or Object ID>'
```

**Apps:**

There is no direct way of achieving this. For a single app, you can go to Setup > App Manager > Your App > Edit and see the list of profiles and their permissions.

For *any app*, this is the closest way I could find:

Get the ApplicationId:

```
SELECT Id, ApplicationId, Name, Label, NamespacePrefix, IsAccessible, IsVisible FROM AppMenuItem
```

(Here, IsAccessible will tell you if the *current user* has access or not)

Then, run this query to see the list of profiles for that application:

```
SELECT Id, SetupEntityId, Parent.IsOwnedByProfile, Parent.ProfileId, parent.Profile.name FROM SetupEntityAccess where SetupEntityId = '<Application ID>' and Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true and SetupEntityType = 'TabSet'
```

Set `Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = false` to check association by permission sets.

**Tabs:**

```
SELECT Name, ParentId, Parent.Profile.Name, Visibility FROM PermissionSetTabSetting
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to query tab assignments as well?

Comment: You can use the PermissionSetTabSetting object to query tab visibility for profiles and permission sets. I have updated the answer to include this.